# Ideablade's Cocktail Composition Container for WCF projects

Tags: ioc-container, devforce

I recently upgraded an application I am working on from Cocktail 1.4 to Cocktail 2.6 (Punch). I have adjusted my bootstrapper class for the wpf project which now loads with no issues. However, on my WCF / Web projects, I am receiving a runtime exception with the following error when attempting to call Composition.GetInstance:

```
"You must first set a valid CompositionProvider by using Composition.SetProvider."
```

After digging into the issue a bit, it appears the composition container is automatically configured when your bootstrapper inherits from CocktailMefBootstrapper. I currently do not have bootstrapper classes at all for non-wpf projects.  Prior to the upgrade, all I had to do was call the configure method on the Composition class to configure the composition container, but it appears that it has been deprecated:

```
Composition.Configure();
```

I noticed that you can also call Composition.SetProvider(), however I am a little unsure on how to satisfy the method signature exactly. The [DevForce Punch documentation](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/cocktail-application-bootstrapper) states that the generic type for the bootstrapper class should be a viewmodel, and there are no views / view models in a service project. This leaves me in limbo on what to do as I don't want to rip cocktail out of these WCF projects. Is there still a way to use Cocktail's composition container without a bootstrapper for a project in Cocktail (Punch) 2.6?

**UPDATE**

I found [this on the DevForce forums](http://forum.ideablade.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=4254&title=bootstrapping-wcf). So it appears that I ought to learn how to configure a multi threaded ICompositionProvider and call Composition.SetProvider() as mentioned above. Any recommended articles to achieving this?

Comment: Take a look at the Punch source code at https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Punch, specifically the MefCompositionProvider.  The MEF CompositionContainer it's using is currently single threaded, but a flag on its constructor will make it multi-threaded.

Comment: Thanks Kim. I actually went through the source code yesterday and came up with a solution. I'll post below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through Punch's source code and looking at Ideablade's MefCompositionContainer, which implements ICompositionProvider, I created my own thread safe implementation of ICompositionProvider. Below is the code I used. Basically, it's the same code for Ideablade's MefCompositionContainer which can be found here [in their repository](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Punch/blob/master/Cocktail/MefCompositionProvider.Desktop.cs). The only change is that I am passing a bool flag of true into the CompositionContainer's constructor. [MSDN lists the pros and cons of making the container thread safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388345(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
internal partial class ThreadSafeCompositionProvider : ICompositionProvider
{
    static ThreadSafeCompositionProvider()
    {
        CompositionHost.IgnorePatterns.Add("Caliburn.Micro*");
        CompositionHost.IgnorePatterns.Add("Windows.UI.Interactivity*");
        CompositionHost.IgnorePatterns.Add("Cocktail.Utils*");
        CompositionHost.IgnorePatterns.Add("Cocktail.Compat*");
        CompositionHost.IgnorePatterns.Add("Cocktail.dll");
        CompositionHost.IgnorePatterns.Add("Cocktail.SL.dll");
        CompositionHost.IgnorePatterns.Add("Cocktail.WinRT.dll");
    }

    public IEnumerable<Assembly> GetProbeAssemblies()
    {
        IEnumerable<Assembly> probeAssemblies = CompositionHost.Instance.ProbeAssemblies;
        var t = GetType();

        // Add Cocktail assembly
        probeAssemblies = probeAssemblies.Concat(GetType().GetAssembly());

        return probeAssemblies.Distinct(x => x);
    }

    private List<Assembly> _probeAssemblies;
    private AggregateCatalog _defaultCatalog;
    private ComposablePartCatalog _catalog;
    private CompositionContainer _container;

    public ComposablePartCatalog Catalog
    {
        get { return _catalog ?? DefaultCatalog; }
    }

    public ComposablePartCatalog DefaultCatalog
    {
        get
        {
            if (_defaultCatalog == null)
            {
                _probeAssemblies = GetProbeAssemblies().ToList();
                var mainCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(_probeAssemblies.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)));
                _defaultCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(mainCatalog);

                CompositionHost.Recomposed += new EventHandler<RecomposedEventArgs>(OnRecomposed)
                    .MakeWeak(x => CompositionHost.Recomposed -= x);
            }
            return _defaultCatalog;
        }
    }

    internal void OnRecomposed(object sender, RecomposedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.HasError) return;

        var newAssemblies = GetProbeAssemblies()
            .Where(x => !_probeAssemblies.Contains(x))
            .ToList();

        if (newAssemblies.Any())
        {
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(newAssemblies.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)));
            _defaultCatalog.Catalogs.Add(catalog);
            _probeAssemblies.AddRange(newAssemblies);
        }

        // Notify clients of the recomposition
        var handlers = Recomposed;
        if (handlers != null)
            handlers(sender, args);
    }


    public CompositionContainer Container
    {
        get { return _container ?? (_container = new CompositionContainer(Catalog, true)); }
    }



    public Lazy<T> GetInstance<T>() where T : class
    {
        var exports = GetExportsCore(typeof(T), null).ToList();
        if (!exports.Any())
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could Not Locate Any Instances Of Contract", typeof(T).FullName));

        return new Lazy<T>(() => (T)exports.First().Value);
    }

    public T TryGetInstance<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (!IsTypeRegistered<T>())
            return null;

        return GetInstance<T>().Value;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetInstances<T>() where T : class
    {
        var exports = GetExportsCore(typeof(T), null);
        return exports.Select(x => (T)x.Value);
    }

    public Lazy<object> GetInstance(Type serviceType, string contractName)
    {
        var exports = GetExportsCore(serviceType, contractName).ToList();
        if (!exports.Any())
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could Not Locate Any Instances Of Contract",
                                              serviceType != null ? serviceType.ToString() : contractName));

        return new Lazy<object>(() => exports.First().Value);
    }

    public object TryGetInstance(Type serviceType, string contractName)
    {
        var exports = GetExportsCore(serviceType, contractName).ToList();
        if (!exports.Any())
            return null;

        return exports.First().Value;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetInstances(Type serviceType, string contractName)
    {
        var exports = GetExportsCore(serviceType, contractName);
        return exports.Select(x => x.Value);
    }

    public ICompositionFactory<T> GetInstanceFactory<T>() where T : class
    {
        var factory = new ThreadSafeCompositionFactory<T>();
        Container.SatisfyImportsOnce(factory);
        if (factory.ExportFactory == null)
            throw new CompositionException(string.Format("No export found.", typeof(T)));

        return factory;
    }

    public ICompositionFactory<T> TryGetInstanceFactory<T>() where T : class
    {
        var factory = new ThreadSafeCompositionFactory<T>();
        Container.SatisfyImportsOnce(factory);
        if (factory.ExportFactory == null)
            return null;

        return factory;
    }

    public void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        // Skip if in design mode.
        if (DesignTime.InDesignMode())
            return;

        Container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
    }

    public bool IsRecomposing { get; internal set; }

    public event EventHandler<RecomposedEventArgs> Recomposed;

    internal bool IsTypeRegistered<T>() where T : class
    {
        return Container.GetExports<T>().Any();
    }

    public void Configure(CompositionBatch compositionBatch = null, ComposablePartCatalog catalog = null)
    {
        _catalog = catalog;

        var batch = compositionBatch ?? new CompositionBatch();
        if (!IsTypeRegistered<IEventAggregator>())
            batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());

        Compose(batch);
    }

    public void Compose(CompositionBatch compositionBatch)
    {
        if (compositionBatch == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("compositionBatch");

        Container.Compose(compositionBatch);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Lazy<object>> GetExportsCore(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        return Container.GetExports(serviceType, null, key);
    }
}
```

After setting up that class, I added a configuration during startup to instantiate my new thread safe composition provider and to set it as the provider for Punch's Composition class:

```
        if (createThreadSafeCompositionContainer)
        {             
            var threadSafeContainer = new ThreadSafeCompositionProvider();
            Composition.SetProvider(threadSafeContainer);
        }
```

Seems to be working like a charm!